# Resx resources (localization) working in debug but not in MSI installer

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, localization, installation

I have a situation, where user can select program language. After selecting it i set `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture` to the selected one, and load the appropriate language text for my controls from resource (.resx) files.

If I run the program from Visual Studio it works perfectly. If I run my release version (install my .msi) it only shows in English.

Comment: It is unlikely you'll get help with amount information you provided. Consider debugging your application and check what UI culture is set at the moment of call and if localized resource assemblies are present. If you don't want to debug - consider adding logging instead...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov unlikely but not impossible! ;) Stack Overflow beats the odds again

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - I have had a go at editing the question so that it can be taken off hold. I believe there was (and now definitely is) more than enough info to be a solid question worthy of being closed for being solved rather than closed for insufficient info

Comment: You need to post the code that illustrates the problem. A brief description like this is not good enough.

Comment: @m2o2r2g2 - with install MSI update it look more reasonable - voting to reopen.

Comment: @Barmar - if you can come up with reasonably-sized sample for setup sample it would be useful... Unfortunately I can't think of one (and C# sample is unlikely to help as code works in debug build).

Comment: I don't understand. You need to post YOUR code that is having the problem. I don't know anything about .net, Visual Studio, or Resx, so I'm not going to provide a sample for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there is a difference between your debug and release builds.
Is the resx included in your build directory for both the debug and the release?

My guess is that you should look at the `Build Action` and `Copy to Output Directory` properties of your resx file.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the problem is with resources. All resx files has `Build Action` set to `Embedded Resource` and `Copy to Output Directory` set to `Do not copy`. Result i get is that after building it, i have multiple `*.resources.dll` files, but only one of them is included into MSI.

Comment: In your installer project - add a new item. Select `Project Output`, select the relevant project and select `Localized resources`

Comment: +1. @JNM - please consider editing your question so it could be found when one faces similar problem. Consider what you would have searched for and update title to match that.